# How do I set up page tags for Google search results?

Tags: kentico

As title suggests, how do I enter page titles into the CMS of V9 kentico so that they are reflected in the Google search for my busines?

Comment: You need to specify more of exactly what you're looking for in your question.  Details are key.

Answer (score 0):

By default Kentico uses the site name and the page's name as the page title.  If you want to set these separate then you can go to the page you want to modify, General>Meta data and edit it there.